# Unable to add map to an activity

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I am adding a google map to my activity. I added exactly the same code as given in this link provided by google : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en
  But my application crashes everytime it starts without showing anything.
This is my Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".map"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBjQrfM9sZcE6SKvQLNhBVYh9PsSmr4wbs"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

content_map.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial.map"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_map">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_map.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial.map">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_map" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

java code :

```
package com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class map extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

this is the ERROR :

```
Process: com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial, PID: 31716
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial/com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial.map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial.map.onCreate(map.java:25)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:384)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

build.gradle(Module : app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sachinparashar.mapstrial"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

I am stuck at it for hours now. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add errors. I am editing my question

Comment: why don't you use the map activity template provided by android studio. You will just have to add your api key to make it running

Comment: @MD I have edited the question. It contains the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add dependency in build.gradle? If not then add it:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

Your build.gradle like this:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    //compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. There are two build.gradle files in my project. one is build.gradle(Project : MapsTrial)  and second, build.gradle(Module : add). I have added this dependency into the second file.

Comment: I think you added namespace: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  &  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  two times in content_map.xml so there will be problem to inflating the layout. So Remove it from <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
& Check it.

Comment: I didn't add namespace. I have added the gradle file also. Please check. Thank you

Comment: Ok. I am deleting it and try.

Comment: No. It didn't help. I just don't get it. Why isn't it working

Comment: adding this dependency helped fix my issue .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your manifest file above Google map API key

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

hope, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Add map fragment at Runtime In your Activity/Fragment.It works for me .

```
private void setMap() {
    GoogleMapOptions options=new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.compassEnabled(false);
    mapFragment=SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mapContainer,mapFragment).commit();
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mapFragment!=null){
            googleMap=mapFragment.getMap();
            if(googleMap!=null){
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                    .title(eventBean.getVenueName()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),10));
            }
        }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ADM But can't I do it in a normal Blank activity?

Comment: Yes you can .. But i have gone threw some problem using it statically so i did it dynamically .. Also add this to your menifest file ..             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />